# Apply CSS file from activated WordPress Plugin

Tags: css, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and want to know best way to add css from installed and activated plugin.
I have one activated plugin called "`social-media`" and in that plugin i have created one css file called "`social-login-style.css`"

I want to `include` this css file and `apply style` to my content. How should I add css file in any page so that I can see the effects.

In Short, I want to add `social-login-style.css` on `wp-login.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is theme or plugin, css or js, any custom addition, `wp_enqueue_scripts` is the only acton you need for all.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts

```
function additional_custom_styles() {

    /* Enqueue The Styles */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-login-style', plugins_url( 'social-login-style.css', __FILE__ ) );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'additional_custom_styles' );
```

If you it to be added only on login screen then use the following condition,

```
if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php' ) {
    // We're on the login page!
}
```

Hope this one help :)

**UPDATE**

Please check `login_enqueue_scripts`. it is designed to add custom scripts into login page only. Works well without any login condition.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts

Comment: It is advisable to test an answer before posting it. [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) only works in frontend. It doesn't work on `wp-login.php` or on `wp-admin.php`.

Comment: yeah it works, but some more condition needed for that. Anyway i have updated my answer with proper function to enqueue :)

Answer (score 0):

Without saying what you want to achieve is impossible, it certainly is against how WordPress is designed to work. Plugins are supposed to be modules that add to or modify how WordPress works. The folder of a plugin should only hold files pertaining to what the plugin does and, if it's a public plugin, its contents are controlled by a versioning (SVN) system.

In short, adding a file to an existing plugin will not have any effect, regardless of whether the plugin is active or not. And you should not add files to plugins you haven't developed yourself.

To load a CSS file on the login page, one should add an action hook to `login_enqueue_scripts`, as instructed in [Customizing Login Form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form) page of the codex. The stylesheet itself should be placed in either a custom plugin (you could create for your use-case) or inside the current theme folder.